# How to make cross site request to Azure's mobile service API?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, azure, cross-domain, jsonp

With Azure's MobileServiceClient, jquery, or AngularJS. Something.. Problem is the service requires custom header and I'm not sure if I can do both..

Comment: stackoverflow is not your own personal noteboard.  Use something like Trello.

Answer (score 0):

Just found I can add hosts to allow CORS in Azure. The rest is just using your flavor of js library to make the ajax call with the custom header. So not exactly magic..